# How to migrate from a http load balancer to a https one with nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, tcp, https, load-balancing

So my load balancer simply looks like this:

```
upstream myapp1 {
    server 192.168.0.20;
    server 8.8.8.8 backup;
}

server {
    listen 80 default;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://myapp1;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

And one of many domain configs on the cluster (`192.168.0.20`) looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /var/www/maximilian.xyz/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name maximilian.xyz www.maximilian.xyz;
   
    ...
}
```

---

### Now for the bit you don't know!

I have been following this [tutorial](https://serversforhackers.com/tcp-load-balancing-with-nginx-ssl-pass-thru) using the `stream {...}` config to attempt to cover the ssl/https/443 in a similar fashion to above:

```
stream {
    upstream myapp1 {
        server 192.168.0.20:443;
        server 8.8.8.8:443 backup;
    }
    
    server {
            listen 443 ssl;
            proxy_pass myapp1;
    }
}
```

And this time I added to the cluster at `192.168.0.20`:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/maximilian.xyz/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/maximilian.xyz/privkey.pem;

    server_name maximilian.xyz www.maximilian.xyz;

    root /NAS/maximilian.xyz/public_html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    ...
}
```

Which when the DNS record points directly to 192.168.0.20 works perfectly (https).

---

But when I run through the load balancer it is not working at all. Everything is fine on nginx when running `service nginx configtest`.

I have ran `tcpdump port 443 and '(tcp-syn|tcp-ack)!=0'` on the load balancer which returns when accessing `https://maximilian.xyz/` but when running on the cluster nothing is picked up which means that the tcp packets are not being passed on, why?

Please let me know if this is a terrible alternative.

Is there a way I can set the SSL certificates at the load balancer and pass those certificates to the clusters? Is that a better method?

---

Comment: I suspect your issue is that you have the 'ssl' enabled in the server block in your stream. You actually just want to purely pass it through, not attempt to interpret it. It's possible nginx is ignoring it (as you're not getting an error), but that's the only thing that stands out.

Comment: @jdewald Will remove it now!

Comment: No luck :( I am really lost as to why this is not working!!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation at http://nginx.org/docs/stream/ngx_stream_upstream_module.html#server :

> The address can be specified as a domain name or IP address with an obligatory port

Yet it appears that your question is missing said port.

As such, perhaps this will do the trick:

```
 stream {
    upstream myapp1 {
-        server 192.168.0.20;
+        server 192.168.0.20:433;
```

(As a sidenote, why are you using 8.8.8.8 as your backup upstream?  Isn't that supposed to be Google's Public DNS service?)

Alternatively, indeed you can setup certificates right at the stream, see http://nginx.org/docs/stream/ngx_stream_ssl_module.html, the SSL directives are basically nearly the same as they are outside of the stream module.  You can then `proxy_pass` it either to an http upstream, or to an https one, using the `proxy_ssl` boolean directive as per http://nginx.org/docs/stream/ngx_stream_proxy_module.html#proxy_ssl.

Comment: Tried the stream changes but no luck. Is there anyway I can debug?

Comment: @Maximilian, what does the error log say?  Did you notice that `stream` is only supported in relatively recent versions of nginx, and even then it is a compile-time option that's disabled by default as shipped by nginx?  Did you have all of these stream modules enabled?

Comment: I have the latest nginx and running `system nginx configtest` returns OK. Is there anyway I can debug if I have the modules enabled?

Comment: @Maximilian, you can use `nginx -V`; what do the error logs say?

Comment: `--with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module` are both in there

Comment: @Maximilian, but you're also using `stream_upstream`, is it there, too?  some errors would be reported through the top-level `error_log`, not the site one.  does the top-level error_log file not have anything, either?

Comment: So within the `http{}` I have `error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;` and that is not showing anything?

Comment: @Maximilian, I think you're doing something wrong that you're not telling us about -- specifying a port is explicitly required, yet it's missing in your question, all whilst you're claiming that some sort of a config test is passing with flying colours

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103144/discussion-between-maximilian-and-cnst).